# Hadoop counters: how to access the Reporter object outside map() and reduce()

Tags: hadoop

To use counters I need to have an access to Reporter object.

The Reporter object is passed as parameter to  map() and reduce(), hence I can do:
 reporter.incrCounter(NUM_RECORDS, 1);

But I need to use counters inside the class MultipleOutputFormat ( I am using method 
generateFileNameForKeyValue )

Question: how to access the Reporter object inside the MultipleOutputFormat class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Could create your own `MultipleOutputFormat` class, `MyMultipleOutputFormat` (which is kinda sounds like you are doing) and create a function that takes in a `Reporter` (as well as the other parameters) that then calls the base `generateFileNameForKeyValue`.

If there is a way you can access the `Job` from where you need to record it. You can get the `context` from the `job` (`context.getConfiguration()` and then increment the counter (`context.getCounter(YOUR_COUNTER.HERE).increment(1);`)

I don't know your exact situation, but attempting to use a counter inside a function that should be acting on/for a single record seems unnecessary and likely could be done 'outside' where access to the `Reporter`/`Context` is easy. I could be wrong and your situation/use of the counter is needed there, but I'd suggest checking if you really need it inside that function, or if it could be done outside as well.

Edit: To respond to the couple of points that were unclear;
Creating a function that takes in a `Reporter`: Since you are extending the `MultipleOutputFormat` you can add additional functions. If you add a function definition of `generateFileNameForKeyValueAndTrack(K key, V value, String name, Reporter reporter)` you can then do the counter incrementation in that function and have it call `generateFileNameForKeyValue` passing along `key`, `value` and `name`.

Using a counter inside seems unneeded: I'm assuming you are calling `generateFileNameForKeyValue` inside the `map` function. Replace `map` with whatever function if that assumption is wrong. Create a collection (don't care what type, as long as it can do what I describe) that you store the generated File Name. Everytime a filename is generated you can check if it exists in the collection and increment the appropriate counter.
I can see the appeal of doing it inside the `generate...` function to avoid duplicating data, so I'd (off the top of my head) probably go with creating the additional function (specified above).

I hope that helps clarify what I was suggestion.

To keep communication flowing properly (and me being notified) if you have comments/questions relating to this post, please use add a comment to this post instead of adding an answer.

Comment: I do not call MyMultipleOutputFormat methods explicitly: I just register this class: job.setOutputFormat(MyMultipleOutputFormat.class) and Hadoop calls methods of this class (e.g. generateFileNameForKeyValue) behind the hood. My main issue is that I do not know how to access the Reporter object: I have an access to JobConf object in MultipleOutputFormat, but JobConf (I think) do not provide an access to Reporter and I do not use Context object, because it is in 0.20 API and I am using 0.19 Hadoop API

Comment: Ahh. Having not worked with `MultipleOutputFormat` I failed to realize it called that automatically, but that makes sense. Outside of those options, maybe see if you can access which filename was generated in the `map` function?